# SpringBoot websecurity doesn't ignore a url if it has params

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websecurity

I was trying to ignore a url from WebSecurity in SpringBoot. Was able to do it for exact url match. But if there is a param in the url itself, it couldn't ignore it. Is there a better way to ignore a url, like ignoring a particular controller. And if not, how to work around with params?

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/v1/something");
    // was able to ignore [url]/api/v1/something but not [url]/api/v1/something?xyz=wjsbjbjbsjbw
}
```

Comment: Add " * " post your URL and it will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/v1/something/**");` should work fine but do check if you had included `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/error/**");` as i was facing similar issue earlier, error endpoints were also getting authenticated . hope this helps.

Comment: This was the issue, I tried debugging the code. The error was being thrown because of the other code.

Answer (score 2):

You should achieve your goal if you would append an asterisks (*) after your current antMatcher specification.

[Per definition:](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html)

> The mapping matches URLs using the following rules:
>
> - ? matches one character
> - * matches zero or more characters
> - ** matches zero or more directories in a path
> - {spring:[a-z]+} matches the regexp [a-z]+ as a path variable named "spring"

The important snippet for your code could look like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/v1/something*");
}
```

You could also achieve the same using the other overloaded configure method with the parameter of type `HttpSecurity` for path related security configurations, which would look as follows:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v1/something*").permitAll();
}
```

As stated in the definition you could also go one step further and allow anything below that path when ending your AntMatcher with `/**`. But this is really dependent on your use case.
For implementation details have a look at [`Spring AntPathRequestMatcher`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AntPathRequestMatcher.java#L114-L142)

---

Your corresponding request mapping should look as follows (example with @GetMapping). It is important, that your path has no trailing `/`.

```
@GetMapping("/api/v1/something")
public ResponseEntity<String> getSomething(@RequestParam(value = "xyz", required = false) String xyz){
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Called with xyz param: " + xyz);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with wildcards.

```
web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/v1/something/**");
```

Comment: didn't work out, but thanks. Still `/api/v1/something` is ignored, but not with params

Answer (score 1):

Try it using `HttpSecurity`

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/something/**").permitAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This Should work for you.

```
[url]/api/v1/something?xyz=wjsbjbjbsjbw
```

replace as below 
"wjsbjbjbsjbw" = *

SO new URL would be

```
[url]/api/v1/something?xyz=*
```

Every value that is after `/` can be considered as `*`.

I am not sure what `something` is else you can make it `*` as well

Or other way around is which will definitely work is

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("[url]/api/v1");
}
```

See [Spring Security Samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-javaconfig/blob/master/samples/preauth/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/samples/config/SecurityConfig.java) for more details

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexmatchers` for the same.

```
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
      web.ignoring().regexMatchers("/api/v1/something.*");
}
```